# ASP MVC load new view on selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, but I cannot find a clear answer anywhere.

I have a page, "Index", in my application. Index contains some graphs and various other data. At the top of the page, I have a HTML drop down menu. When the user selects a value from the drop down menu, it affects the data. The desired behaviour is that the page refreshes with updated graphs.

I'm able to get the value of the drop down menu using

```
 <select id="Menu" onchange="loadGraphs()">
```

and then access the value in a script using:

```
var value = $('#Menu').val();
```

But then I am not able to make a call to my controller to refresh the page. I have a method in the controller that accepts the value, processes the data, and returns the view. How do I call this with the value and have it reload the page?

Comment: Where is the code that isn't working? Can you include that as well?

Comment: Look into making an Ajax call from your index view to the controller. The action called in the controller can then update the content in the index view using partial views.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to reload the page, if all you want is to refresh the data then use a little angular app for example which is able to update the page without refreshing anything.

What you need to do is issue an http request to your controller either GET or POST depending on how you wrote the controller, make it return a JsonResult and then use the result to populate the new data.

The controllers can return data only, not just Views. When it's a view it's an ActionResult, but JsonResult is just that, some json stuff.

A nicer approach would be to add a WebApi2 project and that's where you would put all your data related controllers. It depends on how big your project is though. It could be overkill if all you have is one or two things you need to call. The advantage however is that you could call the same api from multiple clients not just web, like a mobile one for example.

Comment: It hadn't clicked I could simply return some data from a method and plug that into a graph. Wouldn't the page still need to be refreshed top update the display however?

Comment: that's why I suggested Angular which has two way data binding. So basically the display changes when your data changes and that saves you from having to think about refreshing the page at all. If you don't want to worry about such a framework though, you could recreate your data display when the data comes back from your controller and then you don't need to refresh your page at all.